# How to split Emacs over a dual monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, emacs, x-windows

I would like to split Emacs over a double monitor. How do I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

C-x 5 2 or File->New Frame, and then move the new frame to the other monitor.

There is also File->New Frame on Display, to open a new frame on a different X display.